# Log4j setting to NOT create zero-sized log files?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is there a configuration option for a log4j appender for NOT creating zero-sized log files but create a log file ONLY when something was logged for the first time? So to say create-on-demand. I am using log4j 1.2.12 on some legacy system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, no, there is no such option. Although, if you use [Daily Rolling File Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html), a new file will be created only when rollover occurs, and you can define when you want that to happen.