# How to tell Log4j fileAppender to NOT create zero size log files

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

Is there any way I can configure log4j to create a log file only when an error is encountered. 
I have 2 fileAppenders, first logfile records all logs and second one having a threshold of ERROR.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, LOGFILE, ERRORFILE
// more config
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender 
// more config
log4j.appender.ERRORFILE=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ERRORFILE.Threshold=ERROR
```

When I run my application, the ERRORFILE appender always creates the error log file, irrespective of whether LOGGER.error("foo") was run or not.

Can I trigger this ERRORFILE appender to create the logFile when the first LOGGER.error() statement is encountered ? On demand file generation ?

I see a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196604/log4j-setting-to-not-create-zero-sized-log-files), but since it was asked quite a while before, I was wondering if someone has an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The file is created when the appender is configured (i.e. during startup) and not when the appender is used for the first time.

This has to do with the nature of the rolling appender: It might have to clean up existing log files. If no one was logging, then old log files would sit on your hard disk forever. So it runs the cleanup when the appender is created.

I also dimly remember that there were other corner cases which would make that impractical (like several threads logging to the same file).